# Wordpress plugins tinymce conflict

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am using Wordpress and have two plugins installed on there. Both are using the Tinymce WYSIWYG editor. If I have both plugins activated i get the following error message when loading the page plugin B is being displayed:

jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2 **Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for autocomplete widget instance**

When clicking on one of the tabs of tinymce, this error message pops up:

tinymce.min.js?ver=4310-20160418:11 **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshContentEditable' of undefined**

If I have plugin A deactivated, plugin B works flawlessly!

How can the conflict between both plugins be resolved? Shouldn't both just be using the tinymce editor and not changing it for the other plugin?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I recently got the same problem when using Tinymce (advanced) and the tool set types plugin. Did you fix it in some way without disabling one or the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the load order of the plugins in wordpress. By moving the plugin that created the error to an earlier load position the problem could be solved